# Finding the impedance of a distribution line from R,X,C values

Tags: impedance, passive-networks, electrical, power-engineering, python

I have real industry data of distribution feeder with line data consisting of `r ,x` and `c` values as shown in the attached figure.

1. I want to write a script in python to calculate the `impedance of line` based on the above parameters. To achieve this, I tried the below script. Do I calculate it correctly?

   ```
   import numpy as np
   l = 80                                  # Line length [km]
   C = 0.00048 * l                         # Line Capacitance [H]
   R = 0.0754 * l                          # Line resistance [Ohm]
   F = 50                                  # Frequency [Hz]
   w = 2*np.pi*F                           # Frequency [rad / s]
   z = np.sqrt(R**2 + (w*L)**2)            # Impedance (magnitude) [Ohm]


   print("Impedance:",z ,"Ohm")
   ```

[image]

Comment: Line capacitance is not in henries (H). Line impedance has nothing to do with length if you are talking about *characteristic impedance*. We need R, L, G and C per metre or mile of km or foot.